# prevent bootstrap navbar-fixed-bottom overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In some cases the bootstrap [navbar-fixed-bottom](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) will overlap other content without displaying a scrollbar.

For example https://jsfiddle.net/m5vgd9g7/1/:

```
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"
         style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px">
  bottom
</div>
```

If you make the display pane very short vertically, the text "bottom" overlaps the button:

[image]

How can the overlap be prevented, so a vertical scrollbar appears before they overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a class to your top `div` which is `row`, so your top html would look like

```
<div class="row">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
</div>
```

This will add you a scrollbar for your content vertically. But when we declare a fixed navbar you should keep in mind to add a padding/margin to the rest of the content to the size of the navbar, which should display the rest of the content without being intruded by the navbar. So your final html for the top div would look like,

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:15px;">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
</div>
```

Note: I would never use inline styles as it would complicate the html in the long run and hard to debug. I did it here for the sake of demonstration.

And the fiddle example is here : https://jsfiddle.net/m5vgd9g7/

**EDIT**

Thanks to @JDiMatteo who commented about the `row` class addition. I was about to maintain the bootstrap standards in grid system. (ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Apparently it seems `row` should be contained within `container` or `container-fluid` classes for it to work. This will define a row, where elements/columns(as in bootstrap) could reside in. And by using this, you can get rid of the custom styling we used earlier, `padding/margin`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
      Button
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but why did you add a row class?  It seems like the solution is all in the padding-bottom.  The row class seems to force a horizontal scrollbar, which isn't desirable.  e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/mvneb1yy/1/  .  Also, I think you forgot to save your fiddle or something because it doesn't reflect your answer.  (Sorry, I initially also posted a wrong fiddle url.)

Comment: Awe sorry about the fiddle.

Comment: And about the row classes, I was trying to maintain the grid system standards in bootstrap, which uses `row` and `col-..-..` for setting up the grid. Just now I realized `row` class should be contained within a `container` class which should make your life easier. You want be needing to set `padding/margin` to your top div. I'll edit the answer now

Comment: Would you know how to force full height, avoiding scroll bars?